# DialogBox with value verifications

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

For my application which deals with graphics, I've made a little DialogBox to set:

- Max;
- Min;
- Major Step (of the scale);
- Minor Step.

Here's a screen capture:

[image]

I want to validate a few things before allowing the user to click <kbd>Ok</kbd>:

1. Max >= Min
2. MaxScale >= MinScale.

But it's not working as I would: If I set the Min > Max, the textbox is red but the <kbd>Ok</kbd> button is still enabled...

How can I fix that?

Here's my code:

```
public partial class AxisPropertiesDial : Form
{
    public AxisPropertiesDial(string title, double max, double min, double majorStep, double minorStep)
    {
        Max = max;
        Min = min;
        MajorStep = majorStep;
        MinorStep = minorStep;
        InitializeComponent();

        tbMax.Text = max.ToString();
        tbMin.Text = min.ToString();
        tbMajStep.Text = majorStep.ToString();
        tbMinStep.Text = minorStep.ToString();
        Load += OnLoad;
        Text = "Axis: " + title;
    }

    private void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetDesktopLocation(Cursor.Position.X - Size.Width / 2, Cursor.Position.Y - Size.Height / 2);
    }

    public double Max;
    public double Min;
    public double MajorStep;
    public double MinorStep;

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Max = Convert.ToDouble(tbMax.Text);
        Min = Convert.ToDouble(tbMin.Text);
        MajorStep = Convert.ToDouble(tbMajStep.Text);
        MinorStep = Convert.ToDouble(tbMinStep.Text);
    }

    private void ValidateTextBox(TextBox tb, double save, out double valueToAssign, double compareTo, bool greaterThan)
    {
        btnOk.Enabled = false;
        tb.BackColor = Color.Tomato;
        if (!Double.TryParse(tb.Text, out valueToAssign))
        {
            valueToAssign = save;
            return;
        }
        if (greaterThan && (valueToAssign >= compareTo) || !greaterThan && (valueToAssign <= compareTo))
        {
            btnOk.Enabled = true;
            tb.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
        else
        {
            //Rollback
            valueToAssign = save;
        }
    }

    private void ValidateAll()
    {
        ValidateTextBox(tbMax, Max, out Max, Min, true);
        ValidateTextBox(tbMin, Min, out Min, Max, false);
        ValidateTextBox(tbMajStep, MajorStep, out MajorStep, MinorStep, true);
        ValidateTextBox(tbMinStep, MinorStep, out MinorStep, MajorStep, false);
    }

    private void tb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ValidateAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to enable or disable the button when checking individual textboxes and they're conflicting with each other, instead the logic needs to be at a higher level.  Change your textbox validation function to return a `bool`, and use that in `ValidateAll` to determine whether or not to enable the button:

```
private bool ValidateTextBox(TextBox tb, double save, out double valueToAssign, double compareTo, bool greaterThan)
{
    tb.BackColor = Color.Tomato;
    if (!Double.TryParse(tb.Text, out valueToAssign))
    {
        valueToAssign = save;
        return false;
    }
    if (greaterThan && (valueToAssign >= compareTo) || !greaterThan && (valueToAssign <= compareTo))
    {
        tb.BackColor = Color.White;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        //Rollback
        valueToAssign = save;
        return false;
    }
}

private void ValidateAll()
{
    btnOk.Enabled = 
        ValidateTextBox(tbMax, Max, out Max, Min, true) &
        ValidateTextBox(tbMin, Min, out Min, Max, false) &
        ValidateTextBox(tbMajStep, MajorStep, out MajorStep, MinorStep, true) &
        ValidateTextBox(tbMinStep, MinorStep, out MinorStep, MajorStep, false);
}
```

Comment: That's nice, *but* when I put two errors, the second one doesn't turn red... When I debug, just the first two `ValidateTextBox` are executed...

Comment: @Thomas Updated to use the bitwise `&` rather than logical `&&` - this should still function correctly, but bypasses the short circuit evaluation inherent in `&&`